# The affine tangent cone and the number of tangents

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Sorry, I have to improve my question because I can't post my question right now. So, I edited my past question.

Someone answered me

"If you can draw the Affine Tangent Cone in the origin at the
$$y^2 = x^3 + x^2 $$
Then you can know that when there is singularity, You will intuitively understand why it is possible to figure out the number of tangents by considering from that point to the affine tangent cone."

So, If you know about this, could you explain this sentence's meaning?

Comment: Question looks fine, why the -1?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). In particular, write a descriptive title. "How to draw it?" doesn't give any idea about the topic of the question. It's useless.

Comment: thank you for your advice!

Comment: The definition of the tangent cone tells you exactly what to do. Do you know the definition?

Comment: Actually, I know the definition a little.

Comment: If you have a different question, you should ask it as a new post, not edit your old post (which already has an answer!).

Comment: sorry, I can't post a new question

Comment: Sorry, I have to improve my question because I can't post my question right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the variables are real. The function $x^2+x^3$ is  nonegative for $x\geq -1$, so the curve lies to the right of the vertical line $x=-1$ touching it in the single point $y=0$. As you move to the right it touches the line $x=c$ in two points unless $c=0$. The points have $y$-coordinates  $\pm \sqrt{c^3+c^2}$. From the implicit function theorem the only points that could have multiple tangents seems to be $(-1,0)$, and $(0,0)$ .  I think you can get your answer from there.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry to ask you again. What's the meaning of nonegative here?

Comment: Greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: Ah~ I understood it! thank you